# Variable does not get sent when using PHP mail

Tags: php, email

I'm using the following code as a php file while I post my information form an HTML file, Where the user clicks the button after filling in the data. Currently while testing the variables ***($name,$email,$subject,$message)*** do not get sent in the email content except for the rest of the strings.

*index.html*

```
 <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name='name' class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email ID">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="subject" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
        </div> 
         <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

*sendmail.php*

```
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'dhananjayan322@gmail.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" .' Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: maybe you have an error hidden away inside all those suppressed function calls.. Try removing them & Facing the errors head on..!

Answer (score 0):

You must add one single quote before subject:

```
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'dhananjayan322@gmail.com'; // replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Comment: it is not working... i placed single quote before subject